# Preposition and article

Tags: articles

> Gingrich was deposed as Speaker of the House after the election in 1998.

In the above sentence , can we write "deposed as *a* Speaker"? Or can it be "deposed as Speaker" only? Which one is correct? Please explain.

Comment: Hello, Ahmed. 'Please explain me properly' (which is ungrammatical) indicates that you are almost certainly better asking questions over on ELL. This question might be suitable there, but is too basic for ELU.

Answer (score 0):

"Speaker of the House" is a title. See what Macmillan Advanced Language Practice says about it:

[image]

So, yes, "the Speaker of the House" is possible and correct too:

- **THE SPEAKER** STEPS DOWN: The Fall of Gingrich ([source](https://www.nytimes.com/1998/11/07/us/the-speaker-steps-down-the-career-the-fall-of-gingrich-an-irony-in-an-odd-year.html))
- **The Speaker of the House** is the presiding officer of the United States House of Representatives ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives)).